# How to change a lost password of user account with full disk encryption enabled?

Tags: xubuntu, luks, recovery-mode

I have lost the password with Sudo privileges of my computer.  I have searched the internet and this forum and have seen that this is usually rectified by entering recovery mode by holding the left shift after grub menu.  I have full disk encryption enabled which means that I don't have a grub menu.  Once I enter the encryption password it proceeds directly to boot up the OS.  Once booted up I have access to an account with limited privileges but I need to regain Sudo privileges.  How can I boot into recovery mode considering these circumstances?  Thanks.

Comment: One (reasonably) easy way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: @user535733 That should be an answer :)

Comment: @user535733 He has encrypted disk. Do you think that solution is appropriate in this case?

Comment: @Gryu yes, mounting-and-decrypting is similar enough. Folks who have the skill to chroot properly will be able to decrypt too.

Comment: @user535733 this was a ten minute fix, thanks for providing such a nice suggestion!